# How to modify a JSON file in a for loop in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a JSON file called data.json with the following content:

```
{
    "A": "10",
    "BB": {
    "m": "refresh",
    "t": 1100,
    "tt": 1,
    "pp": 0,
    "fp": 0
    },
    "ss": "1",
    "ZZZ": {
    "0": {
        "np": 45,
        "sh": "True",
        "ni": 32,
        "ft": "False",
        "te": "True",
        "t": 23,
        "mm": 21
    }
    },
    "nr": "564"
}
```

I want to a have bash script that does the following task. There is a for loop of i = 1 to 100 iterations. In the first iteration, only 0 in the value of "ZZZ" should be changed to the value of i which is 1. The new content should be written to data.json. In the second iteration, the content of data.json is read and only 1 in the value of "ZZZ" should be changed to the value of i which is 2 now and the new content should be written to data.json. This process executes to the end of the loop. I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Input JSON file and output directory
input_file="data.json"

# Loop from i=1 to 100
for ((i=1; i<=100; i++)); do
    # Copy the original JSON to a new file
    cp "$input_file" "output.json"

    # Modify the JSON file with jq
    jq --argjson new_i "$i" '.ZZZ[$new_i] = .ZZZ[$i - 1] | del(.ZZZ[$i - 1])' "output.json" > "temp.json"

    # Move the modified JSON back to the original file
    mv "temp.json" "data.json"
done
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
jq: 2 compile errors
jq: error: $i is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.ZZZ[$new_i] = .ZZZ[$i - 1] | del(.ZZZ[$i - 1])
```

My question is how to fix the error?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to use `$new_i` in your jq filter if you pass `--argjson new_i "$i"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you are looking for is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1; i<=100; i++)); do
    jq '.ZZZ = {
    '\"$i\"': {
        "np": 45,
        "sh": "True",
        "ni": 32,
        "ft": "False",
        "te": "True",
        "t": 23,
        "mm": 21
        }
    }' "data.json" > "temp.json"

    mv "temp.json" "data.json"
done
```

If you'd like to have distinct files after each write, you can change `mv "temp.json" "data.json"` to `mv "temp.json" "data_$i.json"`

Comment: Why the hardcoded object and not alter the value from data.json?

Comment: This is not really sustainable as you'll need to alter the script if a value in the object changes.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how to fix the error?

You are passing `jq --argjson new_i "$i"` which enables the variable `new_i` in your jq filter, with `$i` as value.

However, you are still using the bash `$i` in the filter, change that to `$new_i`.

---

That said, consider the following filter:

```bash
for i in {1..10}; do 
    jq --arg new_i "$i" '.ZZZ[$new_i] = .ZZZ["0"] | del(.ZZZ["0"])' ff; 
done
```

Here we pass `i` to jq and then

- `.ZZZ[$new_i] = .ZZZ["0"]` 'copy' the object to the new key (since the source will always have the `0` key since you make a copy beforehand)
- `del(.ZZZ["0"])` remove the `0` key object

Combining that with the `for` loop you already have should create the files.